# changePage in multipage sets all pages blank

Tags: jquery-mobile

When I change page using:

```
$.mobile.changePage('#newPage');
```

the browser's url changes correctly, but I see blank page, and I have to refresh the page (`F5`) to see it.

I use PHP to place all pages in one `HTML` (tiny app, of 3 pages), and tried also:

```
$.mobile.changePage('#newPage', { allowSamePageTransition:true });
```

It looks like it starts the animation and then stops for some reason.

More than that: if I go `back` and `forward` using the browser's buttons, all pages are displayed blank, unless I refresh.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Just a thought, do you have any page with the class ui-page-active in your html? I mean in the html you generate in PHP, not in the html with all the jQuery mobile dynamic modifications

Comment: @davids: I hadn't, and now I added, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Ok, do not include it, as it is the class jQuery mobile adds to the active page, and it could lead to troubles if it is hard coded in the html. Could you give examples of your html??